# Hide status bar even when an alert is presented

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, uialertcontroller

I am hiding my status bar on a specific `viewController` using

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

It is working very nice until I present an alert on the screen. When alert is presented status bar appears again, Which I do not want. When alert is dismissed status bar is hidden again.

Comment: What are you using for your alets? `UIAlertView` or `UIAlertController`?

Comment: I am using UiAlertController

Comment: Please check github link to test sample..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `UIAlertController` is now a full-fledged `UIViewController`, you should be able to subclass it and add the same method to the new subclass. Then instanciate your subclass instead of a plain `UIAlertController`.

Untested, but that should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the prettiest solution but since `UIAlertController` is now just a subclass of `UIViewController` you can subclass it and override the `prefersStatusBarHidden` just as you did with your other view controllers.

Everything else stays the same.

Swift3:

```
final class MYAlertController : UIAlertController {
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class named as CustomAlertController and inherit it from UIAlertController

write this method in this class

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
return true
}
```

and whenever you create an alert, create an instance of CustomAlertController and then use it.

Answer (score 2):

### swift 2 version

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

### swift 3 version

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

### To display alert:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "No internet connection", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            print("OK button pressed");
        }

        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)

    }
```

Please check this link to test:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/AlertControllerSample

Comment: I have mentioned I am using this method in my viewController. and you are giving me same method with no explanation ?

Comment: shall i add a link to test the sample project?

Answer (score 1):

Just write an extension, do not create new class.

**Swift 4**

```
extension UIAlertController {
    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance` is set to `false`. Try setting it to `true` for `UIAlertController` which you are trying to create.

Comment: Even after setting modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance true the status bar is still appearing!